# javascript letter to digit hex

Tags: javascript, typescript, hex

Необходима функция, переводящая в десятичные числа hex буквы. `A` -> `10`,
`F` -> `15` и тд. Чем выше будет порог (большие сс, где `X` тоже буква), тем лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let result = parseInt("1f", 16);
console.log(result); // -> 31

result = parseInt("1h", 19);
console.log(result); // -> 36
```

[`parseInt`<sup>mdn</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
Здесь первый параметр - необходимое число, а второй - система счисления.